# joining two tables and result data should contain non duplicate items in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i have two tables like below

student1 table:

```
+---+--------+-----+
|SID|SSection|SRank|
+---+--------+-----+
|  a|       1|    1|
|  b|       2|    2|
|  d|       4|    2|
|  e|       4|    1|
|  c|       3|    4|
+---+--------+-----+
```

student 2 table:

```
+---+--------+-----+
|SID|SSection|SRank|
+---+--------+-----+
|  a|       2|    1|
|  b|       2|    3|
|  f|       4|    2|
|  e|       4|    1|
|  c|       3|    4|
+---+--------+-----+
```

i want to write a select query and  it should give result like below:

```
+---+--------+----------+----------+
|SID|SSection|test1SRank|test2SRank|
+---+--------+----------+----------+
|  f|       4|         0|         2|
|  e|       4|         1|         1|
|  d|       4|         2|         0|
|  c|       3|         4|         4|
|  b|       2|         2|         3|
|  a|       1|         1|         0|
|  a|       2|         0|         1|
+---+--------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Why do you have two such similar tables?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(student1.SID     , student2.SID     )   AS SID,
  COALESCE(student1.SSection, student2.SSection)   AS SSection,
  COALESCE(student1.SRank,    0                )   AS test1SRank,
  COALESCE(student2.SRank,    0                )   AS test2SRank  
FROM
  student1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  student2
    ON  student2.SID      = student1.SID
    AND student2.SSection = student1.SSection
ORDER BY
  1, 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a986/3

Comment: Hi @MatBailie, actually output requires 2 rows for SID=A because of different SSection values (1 and 2)

Comment: I got A,1,1,1 a single row

Comment: @Eralper Apologies, there was a typo *(`AND student2.SSection = student2.SSection` was wrong, but has now been corrected)*.

Comment: Yes it is as expected now!

Answer (score 1):

Another way with UNION asn CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  [SID],
            SSection,
            SRank as test1SRank,
            0 as test2SRank
    FROM student1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  [SID],
            SSection,
            0 as test1SRank,
            SRank as test2SRank
    FROM student2
)

SELECT  [SID],
        SSection,
        MAX(test1SRank) as test1SRank,
        MAX(test2SRank) as test2SRank
FROM cte
GROUP BY [SID],
        SSection
```

Output:

```
SID  SSection    test1SRank  test2SRank
---- ----------- ----------- -----------
a    1           1           0
a    2           0           1
b    2           2           3
c    3           4           4
d    4           2           0
e    4           1           1
f    4           0           2
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of the same query is as follows producing the same output with the second query

```
;with cte as (

    select
        SID, SSection, SRank as test1SRank, null as test2SRank
    from student1 s1

    union all

    select
        SID, SSection, null as test1SRank, SRank as test2SRank
    from student2 s2

)
select
    SID, SSection, 
    isnull(max(test1SRank),0) test1SRank, 
    isnull(max(test2SRank),0) test2SRank
from cte
group by 
    SID, SSection
```

Could you please try following SQL CTE expression with DENSE_RANK() function

```
;with cte as (

    select
        SID, SSection, SRank as test1SRank, null as test2SRank
    from student1 s1

    union all

    select
        SID, SSection, null as test1SRank, SRank as test2SRank
    from student2 s2

), cte2 as (
select
*,
DENSE_RANK() over (partition by SID order by SSection) as rn
from cte
)
--order by SID
select
    SID, SSection, 
    isnull(max(test1SRank),0) test1SRank, 
    isnull(max(test2SRank),0) test2SRank
from cte2
group by 
    SID, SSection, rn
```

Comment: What does the `DENSE_RANK()` achieve?  To me it looks like it would be correct ***without*** the second CTE and just grouping by `SID, SSection`